# Client Resteasy with LocalDateTime

Tags: java-8, resteasy, jackson-modules

I trying to use the Resteasy CLIENT to call one REST service

In my Service I create with springboot and return one LocalDateTime propert

If I use this depencency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my code in my bean:

```
private LocalDateTime dtPublicacao;
```

this is the result when I call my service:

> dtPublicacao: "2017-04-20T00:00:00"

if I remove this the result:

```
dtPublicacao: {
  hour: 0,
  minute: 0,
  second: 0,
  nano: 0,
  dayOfYear: 110,
  dayOfWeek: "THURSDAY",
  month: "APRIL",
  dayOfMonth: 20,
  year: 2017,
  monthValue: 4,
  chronology: {
    id: "ISO",
    calendarType: "iso8601"
  }
}
```

So in my Client I create the same model and use this to execute the Get

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8585").path("/edital/");
        try{
            List<EditalVO> response = target.request().get(new GenericType<List<EditalVO>>(){});
            return response;
        }catch (NotFoundException e) {          
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
```

So, if I put in my client the LocalDateTime I got this error:

> Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.time.LocalDateTime]
>   from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method (through
>   reference chain:
>   br.com.lumera.protesto.edital.vo.EditalVO["dtExpiracao"])

to solve I need to change in my client form LocalDateTime to Date and add

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
private Date dtPublicacao;
```

I Already try to add the same dependency in my client, but he register the LocalDateTimeSerializer.class but when I call the REST he dot no go through the serialize method and I got the error again.

Can I RECEIVE AND SEND LocalDateTime from my Restasey CLIENT ??

tks

***UPDATE***
I already try to does this too:

```
ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();
obj.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
```

with no success, then I try to in my client :

```
client.register(obj);
```

with no success to.. if I debug my app, he enter on methods

```
public LocalDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter f) {
    super(LocalDateTime.class, f);
}

private LocalDateTimeSerializer(LocalDateTimeSerializer base, Boolean useTimestamp, DateTimeFormatter f) {
    super(base, useTimestamp, f);
}
```

in LocalDateTimeSerializer but don`t enter in serialize method or deserialize

Comment: the [javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Configurable.html#register(java.lang.Object)) says: register an extension provider or a feature meta-provider instance can be used in the scope of this context.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure, but seems like you need to have this [dependency](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310)

and register the module via

```
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

Comment: yes, you are right. the test has been assert that you must register the [JavaTimeModule](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310/blob/master/src/test/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/ModuleTestBase.java#L14) before [deserialization](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310/blob/master/src/test/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/TestLocalDateTimeDeserialization.java#L18).

Comment: @holi-java you took the time to look at the actual tests, not bad!

Comment: I believe the first-line programmers when I'm not sure how to use the library, It will not take much time just a few minutes if the intent is clearly .

Comment: Hi,  Eugene. and the pattern of the  `@JsonFormat` of the OP should be  `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"` in client side.

Comment: @Eugene I already try to does this.. I will update my question with my test

Comment: @Eugene I not using spring or another framework so how is the corretly way to register? tks

Comment: @FabioEbner how are getting a hold of `ObjectMapper` then?

Comment: @Eugene I don`t understand your question

Comment: @FabioEbner doing this `ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();` has no effect. You need the `ObjectMapper` that is currently in use. Where are you deploying your application? U said u are not using `Spring`, but what then? Plain Servlets? How are you exposing your REST Apis?

Comment: @Eugene :), he used resteasy-client module, I think he don't know how to config `ObjectMapper` into the module.

Answer (score 0):

How to config `ObjectMapper` into resteasy-client module? you can see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012686/custom-jackson-serializer-of-resteasy-client/29019303#29019303).

---

I have wrote two tests how one side to fit another side on [github](https://github.com/holi-java/api-test/blob/adaf83c2e1d5251c845e007e71d92d0c60157237/src/test/java/test/jackson/Jackson2JavaTimeModuleTest.java#L28-L44).

## fit client side to server side

If you want to the client side to fit the server side you must set the pattern DateFormat to `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"`, for example:

```
ObjectMapper#setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"))
```

**OR** you can using `@JsonFormat` as:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
private Date dtPublicacao;
```

## fit server side to client side

If you want to the server side to fit the client side you must set the pattern DateTimeFormatter to `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`, for example:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Module module = new JavaTimeModule().addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class
                                      ,new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(formatter));

ObjectMapper#registerModule(module);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the environment "java se app + resteasy-client 6" (not spring, not wildfly/jboss) only this helped, gazillion other methods didn't:

1. usual dependency in pom

   com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype
        jackson-datatype-jsr310
        2.16.1
    /dependency>
2. Adding new class ObjectMapperProvider

   @Provider
   public class ObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver {
   static final JsonMapper MAPPER = JsonMapper.builder()
   .findAndAddModules()
   .build();

   @Override
   public ObjectMapper getContext(final Class<?> type) {
   return MAPPER;
   }
   }
3. Register ObjectMapperProvider strictly in target, not client.

   ResteasyClient client = (ResteasyClient)ClientBuilder.newBuilder().newClient();

   SomeAPI api = client
   .target(UriBuilder.fromPath("https://api.api.cc/"))
   .register(new ObjectMapperProvider())
   .proxy(SomeAPI.class);