# How can I register and use the jackson AfterburnerModule in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-modules

I am using SpringBoot 1.5.9., Jackson 2.8 and Spring Framework 4.3.13.

I am trying to register and use the AfterburnerModel.

According to the Spring Boot documentation, to configure the ObjectMapper you can either define the bean yourself and annotate it with @Bean and @Primary. In the bean you can register a module. Or you can add a bean of type Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder where you can customize the ObjectMapper, by adding a module.

I have tried both ways, and during serialization none of my breakpoints in jackson-module-afterburner fire. My customizations are being read, but seem to be being ignored.

Answer (score 13):

By default Spring MVC `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` will create its own `ObjectMapper` with default options using `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`. As per Spring Boot docs [76.3 Customize the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html) chapter:

> Any beans of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module are automatically registered with the auto-configured Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder and are applied to any ObjectMapper instances that it creates. This provides a global mechanism for contributing custom modules when you add new features to your application.

so it should be enough to register your module as a bean:

```
@Bean
public AfterburnerModule afterburnerModule() {
  return new AfterburnerModule();
}
```

A more detailed setup can be achieved with `@Configuration` class to customize the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`:

```
@Configuration
public class MyMvcConf extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

  protected void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(myConverter());
    addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(converters);
  }

  @Bean
  public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter myConverter() {
    return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(myObjectMapper())
  }

  @Bean
  public ObjectMapper myObjectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new AfterburnerModule());
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that. As I mentioned in the original post the bean is being read. The problem I suspect is that other ObjectMappers are being created and used for example by AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter

Comment: Updated the answer, most likely your new `ObjectMapper` is not configured as part of the Spring MVC converters.

Comment: Interesting, but the same problem. Here is the current stacktrace where the defualt objectmapper is being created:          
ObjectMapper.<init>() line:  
JsonMapperConfigurator.getDefaultMapper() 
ResteasyJackson2Provider(ProviderBase).locateMapper(Class<?>, MediaType)

Comment: You seem to be using JAX-RS with RESTEasy which is not mentioned in your question. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/29019303/1602555.

Comment: Do you notice a performance improvement after adding afterburner? Do you know if this works with spring kafka's jsonserializer?

Comment: When using Beans where do you register the bean? What class?